# Optimize a Cypher Query with loop for builing a time tree

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

I want to create a time tree for a calendar function - it works but I realize that it is very slow (1 insert per 20 seconds). Maybe anyone has a hint how the code shall be changed to gain more perofmance?

```
for ($calYear=2012;$calYear<2016; $calYear++)
{
        $paramsYear =array(
        "pYear" => $calYear, 
        "UUID" => uniqid()            
    );


$queryString = '
    MERGE (y:calTime:calYear {name: {pYear}}) 
    SET 
    y.uuid= {UUID},
    y.created="'.time().'",
    y.active="Y"    
    return y;
    ';

    $query = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $queryString,$params);
    $result = $query->getResultSet();    

    for ($calMonth=1;$calMonth<13; $calMonth++)
    {
                $paramsMonth =array(
                "pYear" => $calYear, 
                "pMonth" => $calMonth, 
                "UUID" => uniqid()            
            );            
        $queryString = '
            MATCH (y:calTime:calYear {name: {pYear}})
            MERGE (m:calTime:calMonth {name: {pMonth}) -[:IS_MONTH_OF]->(y) 
            SET 
            m.uuid= {UUID},
            m.created="'.time().'",
            m.active="Y"    
            return m;
            ';

            $query = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $queryString,$paramsMonth);
            $result = $query->getResultSet();    

            $numberOfDays = date("t",mktime(0, 0, 0, $calMonth, 1, $calYear));

            for ($calDay=1;$calDay<=$numberOfDays; $calDay++)
            {
                    $paramsDay =array(
                    "pYear" => $calYear, 
                    "pMonth" => $calMonth, 
                    "pDay" => $calDay, 
                    "UUID" => uniqid()            
                );  

                $queryString = '
                    MATCH (y:calTime:calYear {name: {pYear}) -- (m:calTime:calMonth {name: {pMonth})
                    MERGE (d:calTime:calDay {name: {pDay}) -[:IS_DAY_OF]->(m)
                    SET 
                    d.uuid= {UUID},
                    d.created="'.time().'",
                    d.active="Y" 
                    return d;
                    ';

                    $query = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $queryString,$paramsDay);
                    $result = $query->getResultSet();                   

                    for ($calHour=1;$calHour<=24; $calHour++)
                    {
                    $paramsHour =array(
                    "pYear" => $calYear, 
                    "pMonth" => $calMonth, 
                    "pDay" => $calDay, 
                    "pHour" => $calHour, 
                    "UUID" => uniqid()            
                );  

                        $queryString = '
                            MATCH (y:calTime:calYear {name: {pYear}) -- (m:calTime:calMonth {name: {pMonth}) -- (d:calTime:calDay {name: {pDay}) 
                            MERGE (h:calTime:calHour {name: {pHour}) -[:IS_HOUR_OF]->(d)
                            SET 
                            h.uuid= {UUID},
                            h.created="'.time().'",
                            h.active="Y"  
                            return h;
                            ';

                            $query = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $queryString,$paramsHour);
                            $result = $query->getResultSet();

                    } // End Hour

            } // End Day
    } // End Month                
} // End Year
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not surprising, your code will execute x distinct http queries for each Cypher statement, which doesn't use all the benefits of the http transactional endpoint. So for each query you have the http latency counting in the query times.

1. Make an array of all the queries you want to execute and execute them all at once, I don't know how neo4jphp will do it but in [NeoClient PHP](https://github.com/neoxygen/neo4j-neoclient) you can easily do it with a PreparedTransaction object
2. There are neo4j plugins that will handle the timetree creation/updates for you under the hood, https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree and there is a [NeoclientPHP timetree extension](https://github.com/graphaware/neoclient-timetree-extension) providing you the required methods to work with the neo4j timetree plugin API

Comment: Thanks, the hint with transaction was valuable!